# Is there any way to handle func props in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

When I finish submitting sign up form and get success data, I want to go back to login form.

Is there any way to call func props in `onSubmitForm`?

main.js

```
const [goToRegister, setGoToRegister] = useState(false);

const onClickGoToRegister = useCallback(() => {
  setGoToRegister(prev => !prev);
}, []);
...

<Modal
  title={goToRegister ? "register" : "login"}
  visible={showModal}
  onCancel={onCancel}
  footer={null}
>
  {goToRegister ? (
    <SignUpForm onClickGoToRegister={onClickGoToRegister} />
  ) : (
    <LogInForm onClickGoToRegister={onClickGoToRegister} />
  )}
</Modal>;
```

As you see, I pass 'onClickGoToRegister' func as props to `SignUpForm`.

SignUpForm.js

```
const onSubmitForm = useCallback(
  e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch({
      type: SIGN_UP_REQUEST,
      data: {
        name: name,
        email: `${email}@${tail}`,
        password: password,
        phone: `${phoneHead}${phoneBody}${phoneTail}`
      }
    });
    if (signUpErrorReason) {
      return message.error(signUpErrorReason);
    }
  },
  [
    name,
    email,
    tail,
    password,
    passwordCheck,
    phoneHead,
    phoneBody,
    phoneTail,
    signUpErrorReason
  ]
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make that dispatcher into a promise or async function.
if you are using redux-thunk , i recommend using [redux-promise](https://github.com/redux-utilities/redux-promise) which converts dispatchs into promises

if that dispatch action is async , you can just do

```
dispatch()
 .then(() => {
    props.onClickGoToRegister()
  })
```

or by using await

```
useCallback(async e => {
  // do stuff
 await dispach({})
 props.onClickGoToRegister()
})
```